# Displaying the result of a mathematical expression between a number and %d in printf using Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a for loop which represents the ASCII values of the letters in a string. I want to cipher the string, therefore while displaying ASCII values, I want to change them by adding a number. Here is my loop;

```
for (( i=0; i<${#string}; i++ )); do
                printf "%d + $number\n" "'${string:$i:1}"
done
```

For example my string is : hey and the number that I want to add to the ASCII values is : 3

Output is like that;

```
104 + 3

101 + 3

121 + 3
```

However, I want to display as;

```
107

104

124
```

I tried to implement expr`%d + $number` into the code but it did not worked. Any help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the resulting expression to get the desired result. `printf` prints what you asked you to print, it doesn't evaluate expressions. You can store the result in a variable and print as:

```
for ((i = 0; i<${#string}; i++)); do
    j=$(printf "%d + $number\n" "'${string:$i:1}")
    echo $((j))
done
```

`(( ))` performs the arithmetic evaluation - see [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for more details.